# Best azure service to send a string to 1 million end user applications - event grid still in preview?

Tags: azure, scalability, azureservicebus, azure-eventgrid

I am trying to find the best service to accomplish a task where 1 event generator would need to send a simple string to potentially 1 million end users / local applications across the country.  Think of this like a mass notification system, or a chat reaching 1 million friends. The requirement is for all to be received under 30 seconds. A small amount of messages CAN be missed. Microsoft staff on the forums have pointed me to using the 'event grid' service for this task.

However, the event grid pricing documentation states that 'You can have up to 1,000 Event Grid subscriptions during the preview period'.  If the limit to subscribers is 1000, this service would not meet my requirements.  So, is event grid still in preview?  If not, what is the current subscription limit?  If it is still in preview, when will preview end?  I cannot accurately estimate cost if I do not know what my limits are, and I cannot start coding a solution if the event grid will not scale to 1 million endpoints.

Is there a better way?  Azure service bus seems like it could handle 1 million subscribers, but this would be polling and would cost orders of magnitude more from what I gather from pricing calculators.

Any information or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: are you sending notifications to smartphones ?

Answer (score 1):

Event Grid support several subscription endpoint types:

[image]

Assuming you're building a chat-like applicaiton, for one million individuals you'd need one million connections. None of these subscription endpoints would match your schenario.

Instead, I would advise to look into [Azure SignalR service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-signalr/), which is exactly tailored for scenarions such as yours.

> What is SignalR Service used for?
>
> ... application types that require real-time content updates
>
> - Apps that require high frequency updates from the server. Examples are gaming, social networks, voting, auction, maps, and GPS apps.
>
> Collaborative apps. Whiteboard apps and team meeting software are examples of collaborative apps.
>
> Apps that require notifications. Social networks, email, chat, games, travel alerts, and many other apps use notifications.

You'll have to find out how many messaging units you'll need and how much it will cost you using pricing [details](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/signalr-service/).

Comment: Thanks Sean.  In looking at SignalR pricing it states: Includes 1,000 concurrent connections per unit and 2,000,000 messages per unit/day. Maximum of 10 units can be configured.  This I read as a total connection limit of 10,000 (10 unit max times 1,000 concurrent connections per unit).  That does not meet the requirement of scalability to 1 million users either.  Depending on how quickly an event perpetuates, perhaps it is possible to send message to current 1000 concurrent connections within unit, then change those connections and send another batch multiple times within the 30s requirement?

Comment: Azure SignalR is still in preview, so these numbers could be artificially kept low. I've pinged MSFT to get an answer for the quotas once it goes into production. One thing I could not understand from your question is do you need bi-directional communication or not. i.e. would pushing notifications to those 1M concurrently connected clients suffice or not. Perhaps you could elaborate more on the use case.

Comment: Two way communication for this message is NOT needed.  1 notification generator 'broadcast' to the potential 1M end users.  To clarify the 1 million connections do NOT need to be all 'concurrent'.  As I questioned if possible, it would suffice for example to send say 10 batches of the same signal, each taking 3 seconds in serial, still ending with 1 million users all getting the message within 30 seconds.  Some breakage is acceptable too, say a loss of 5%.

Comment: Ok, so those are not 1M concurrenly connected users. Then what is it? I'm trying to understand the business case. If there's that many concurrent users/devices, then my recommendation is not even suitable. Email would work just well. If those IoT devices, then there's a different service. You get the idea.

Comment: I need user app to handle message - no email.  I suggested a non concurrent way only because it does not seem that 1M is supported anywhere. If I can connect to 10k clients of the 1M, push a message, then disconnect those and connect to the next 10k clients, 100 times in 30 seconds, then all the users who need it get it in the required time still. Yet here 99% of clients waiting for connection continually. Could 1 million user apps continually read a storage table element 'concurrently'? Reading every 15 seconds would cost up of $150K a month, but that's only 15 cents per user and feasible.

Comment: Once SignalR is out of preview, it will have a much higher limit, but feels like it's not the right tool for this problem. With SignalR clients are connected for two-way communication. I'm still failing to understand what these clients are. I.e. what's the business scenario we're discussing here. Having 1M concurrent users polling a table doesn't sound right to me TBH. I'd rather go in the direction of notifications. Again, w/o understanding the problem at a larger scale instead of a narrow usage is making any recommendation here problematic...

Comment: I agree that a notification type scenario is ideal. So yes, signalR would have unneeded two-way comms.  Business scenario should be irrelevant (and secret sauce right?) if stating the problem correctly. I have the need, and willingness to pay for a service to handle delivering a string generated at random times of day to upwards of 1 million end user apps that clients could be running.  I want to have the message handled by those local end user apps (so no email or SMS gateway). These messages need to reach all running local user apps in a timely manner which is desired to be under 30 seconds.

Comment: I'll connect you with SignalR team for further details. Ping me feldman.sean at gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

Updating Answer Below:

Regarding Event Grid: There is a SLA available with Event Grid Service and I could not find anywhere if it is in preview. So I am assuming it is not in preview now.

Update: I could not find subscriber limits for Event Grid in Documentation. I am running my own test to verify how many subscribers can be created. Will update in  a while.

Update 2: Event Grid is now generally available. 
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/roadmap/azure-event-grid/

Update 3: There is a Limit of 500 Subscriptions per Topic.

Comment: don't think the question was about emailing. Also, there are bulk email providers such as SendGrid that are whitelisted and provide email blasts for pennies.

Comment: I would like the ability to handle the event on the end user side but email could be an alternative.  Could services such as sendGrid get close to the requirement that all million emails are received within 30 seconds?